# Is there any function to check the location of the last date element in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, date

The sample data is like:

| Empty header |
| --- |
| '2/01/2011' |
| '3/01/2011' |
| '4/01/2011' |
| '5.222' |
| '6.214' |
| '1.34266' |

The data above are all strings.

My expected outcome is

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2/01/2011 | 5.222 |
| 3/01/2011 | 6.214 |
| 4/01/2011 | 1.34266 |

The 'Date' variable should be in date format, 'Value' variable is in float.

Comment: Are there always 6 rows including 3 dates and 3 values? Please provide the code that you have tried so far.

Comment: No, since there are multiple datasets, each of them may not have same numbers of rows(i.e., 8 rows including 4 dates and 4 values)

Comment: Actually, I only have a draft: First, convert strings into numeric (but in python it can only be integer or float?) Second, using for loop to convert the date into date format. I try to avoid using for loop, since it is inefficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example**

```
s = pd.Series(['2/01/2011', '3/01/2011', '4/01/2011', '5.222', '6.214', '1.34266'])
```

`s`

```
0    2/01/2011
1    3/01/2011
2    4/01/2011
3        5.222
4        6.214
5      1.34266
dtype: object
```

**Code**

```
cond1 = s.str.contains(r'\d+/')
out = (s.groupby(cond1, sort=False).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(x)))
       .unstack(level=0).set_axis(['Date', 'Value'], axis=1))
```

`out`

```
    Date        Value
0   2/01/2011   5.222
1   3/01/2011   6.214
2   4/01/2011   1.34266
```

Comment: In r'\d+/', do r means strings and \d+ means one or more [0-9], / means a literal forward slash?

Comment: yeah. because I didn't know your data exactly, and if the values ​​are all float types, you can just use `'/'` instead `r'\d+/'`